# slaves not being shown on web browser in hbase multi node

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have installed hadoop(1.2.1) multinode on 1 master and 2 slaves. Now I am trying to install hbase over it. The problem is that when I start hbase on the master, it only shows one regionserver(the master itself) while the slaves are not being shown on the web browser. On the terminal each slave has its own regionserver but that is not reflected on the browser. Can anyone tell me as to what the problem is?

Comment: Were you able to see DataNode's in the NameNode's web page ?

Comment: hadoop is perfectly working

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, i solve it by adding port number in `hbase.rootdir`

And your `hbase-site.xml` should look like this

```
    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>master-IP-Adress,slave1-IP,slave2-IP</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/ravi/zookeeper-data</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper config zoo.cfg.
    The directory where the snapshot is stored.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master-IP:50000/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
      false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
      true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
    </description>
  </property>
```